# Impedance in sine DC

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc, inductor, impedance

If we have a DC sine signal. Can we say that capacitors and inductors have impedance despite not being AC?

If yes then what will the formula look like?

And the opposite if we have an AC square signal do capacitors and inductors have impedance?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by DC sine signal ? If possible a mathematical expression representing such a signal.

Comment: For an AC suqare signal, the signal can be represented as the sum several sinusoids at different frequencies and amplitudes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) and analysis can be done separately for each sinusoid term (subject to some contstraints).

Comment: Sine DC is a signal produced by a full wave bridge rectifier without filters.

Comment: You mean like this ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsed_DC ) ?. Like the square wave, this can also be represented as the sum of pure DC and several sinusoids at different frequencies and amplitudes.

Comment: Yes pulsed DC  is what I mean.

Comment: *pulsed DC is what I mean* That's DC + a pulsed shape signal, the pulse shaped signal **has a value that varies over time** and that means it is AC. DC does **not** vary over time. If it does, it is considered AC.

Comment: But the direction of current doesn't change why is it considered AC it is just an alternating DC.

Comment: If it alternates at any rate, it's AC. It's only DC if it does not alternate even the slightest bit.

Comment: So a varying DC current is considered AC?

Comment: @Maddy, there are two ways of looking at it: (1) If we look at the overall current waveform and it varies but never changes direction then it's DC because the current is not alternating direction (and passing through zero). (2) If we consider the waveform as the sum of a DC and AC waveform we can, by definition, consider that it has an AC componenent.

Answer (score 2):

Capacitors and inductors always have impedance, at all frequencies, including 0 which is DC.

There is no DC sine. At DC, frequency is 0, so capacitor has impedance of infinity so it is an open circuit and inductance has impedance of zero so it is a short circuit. AC signal has a frequency, and ideal square wave consists of harmonic frequencies up to infinity, so yes, capacitors and inductors have impedance at all frequencies.

Recitified AC is also AC, even if it has an average DC component.

Answer (score 2):

> *If we have a DC sine signal. Can we say that capacitors and inductors
> have impedance despite not being AC?*

When we talk about the impedance of an inductor or capacitor we are talking about one single frequency (a sine-wave) with **no** DC offset: -

$$|X_L| = 2\pi F L$$

And

$$|X_C| = \dfrac{1}{2\pi F C}$$

Where \$F\$ is a single operating frequency in hertz.

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{There's no room to consider DC or multiple frequencies}}}$$

> *And the opposite if we have an AC square signal do capacitors and
> inductors have impedance?*

If we want to consider how the current might flow for an arbitrary voltage signal then we revert to the basic relationships: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

And

$$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

For the inductor with a "square signal", when the voltage is +V, the current rises (\$\frac{di}{dt}\$) at a rate of \$\frac{v}{L}\$ amps per second and, when the "square signal" is -V, the current falls at a rate of \$\frac{v}{L}\$.

If we did the same for a capacitor, the rate of change of voltage (\$\frac{dv}{dt}\$) is infinite when the "square signal" switches so we get a pulse of infinite current. But we could assume that the "input" is current and that the current forms a square wave - now we'd get a very similar result for the inductor driven with a square voltage.

Comment: "*When we talk about the impedance of an inductor or capacitor we are talking about one single frequency (a sine-wave) with no DC offset:*" This got me thinking, Andy. What difference does a DC offset make to the impedance of a capacitor? None, I think.The inductor case is conceptually a little more difficult as DC current will flow through it but the impedance at the AC frequency will be the same provided we haven't saturated the core of the inductor. Am I missing something in your thinking?

Comment: there is no "basic relationship" like _V = L*dI/dt_. Do you mean _EMF = -L*dI/dt_ here?

Comment: @Transistor no you're not missing anything - impedance is exclusively to do with sinewaves.

Comment: @V.V.T - what is the formula for current flow in an inductor when a fixed voltage is applied - it is this: $$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

Comment: Current change in inductor produces EMF, not a voltage drop. Internal resistance does produces voltage drop across a non-ideal inductor, but it is altogether other story

Comment: And you give a formula for voltage drop expressed via current change, but call it "the formula for current flow"

Comment: Andy, so why the emphasis on "**no** DC offset"?

Comment: At best, your _V = L*dI/dt_ is inferred from a basic relationship for EMF and Kirchhoff's for a serial network of **ideal** voltage source and **ideal** inductor, but do not call this formula "basic relationship"

Comment: @V.V.T no, if you apply 1 volt across 1 henry the current will ramp at 1 volt per second. I do not understand where you are coming from regards this. It is a basic relationship as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Transistor because it clouds the issues especially with inductor impedance.

Comment: "1 volt across 1 henry the current will ramp at 1 volt per second" is not a "basic relationship". Let us agree to disagree on "basic relationship" concept, OK?

Comment: @V.V.T if you are dissatisfied with my answer I suggest you take the appropriate measures and leave an answer of your own. If you don't regard it as a basic relationship then that's fine.

Comment: Me and many other people do not regard a formula equating voltage source's voltage with current change times inductance for a serial network of ideal voltage source and ideal inductor as a "basic relationship". If you have a different idea on this subject and publish your idea in an educational resource, someone must correct you. Unfortunately, this time it's me. Really, I'm sorry.

Comment: @V.V.T don't waste your time with me, take it up with [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/ee-natural-and-forced-response/a/wmc-inductor-in-action) who also use the same basic formula. While you are doing that please complain to [All about circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-15/inductors-and-calculus/) for them using the formula as I have. They call it "ohms law for an inductor".

Comment: Please don't bother me any more with this. I'm serious.